# Буферизация видео, предварительная загрузка

Tags: javascript, html, html5, видео

Возможно ли организовать предварительную подгрузку видео, не внося изменения в html документ?

То есть, чтобы когда вставляем ссылку на Ролик, в html тег video. Чтобы видео не подгружалось, а было уже готово к воспроизведению хотя бы первые 5сек.

В данный момент, крутится идея, секунт за 10 вставлять в html тек video со ссылкой. Чтобы оно начало буферизироваться, а через 10 сек просто вставить в основной тег video. По мне данный способ не практичный, вероятно есть решение при котором не придется предварительно изменять html документ.

Comment: Был как-то момент, если есть видео на руках, то нужно его поправить, перенести метаданные в начало, тогда видео в целом будет грузится быстрее.

Comment: Можно поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: Точно сказать не могу, этим занимался бэк, но вот этот [вопрос](https://qna.habr.com/q/494970) кажется может помочь. Так же как вариант можно разбить видео на кусочки и подгружать их, либо воспользоваться форматом [m3u8](https://www.online-convert.com/ru/file-format/m3u8). Ну и как вариант закинуть ещё на CDN)

Comment: попробуй эти атрибуты: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload +++ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload

Comment: Это понятно, но для этого придется предварительно вставить html тег video, чтобы запустить процесс